# "Login failed for user" as "The underlying provider failed on Open" in Azure SQL

Tags: azure, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build a small Web API that uses an Azure SQL Database. The database functionality is exposed via Stored Procedures and in order to call them, I am using Entity Framework for .NET, version 6.4.4 as it gives me access to the .edmx Data Model. I have properly configured the EF so that I can see the SPs and I've added one of them to my model. In my controller, I execute this piece of code:

```
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
var result = dbContext.MyStoredProc();
```

I get an exception when the "MyStoredProc()" method gets called. The exception that is thrown is this:

[image]

For now, the connection string is configured to use SQL Authentication, so the user listed in the exception is the user that is configured in the connection string.

I can call the same SP no problems if I use SQL Server Management Studio, within a session open with the same user name and password as I have configured in the connection string.

Why is my application throwing up that exception? Are there specific privileges that I must elevate, in order for the connection to the database to be opened from my Web API?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Eddie

Comment: Pls check `connectionStrings` in `App.config`. For more details, you can check the post which name is [Timeout period elasped prior to obtaining a connection from the pool - Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062815/timeout-period-elasped-prior-to-obtaining-a-connection-from-the-pool-entity-fr/63069572#63069572).

Comment: If there is any progress, please let me know so that it can help you better.

Comment: @JasonPan You were right, there was a problem in the connection string. I checked it a million times, but somehow I missed that the password was misspelled. I wish I can mark your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In projects that use Entity Framework, an error message usually reports that there is no `Login failed for user`. At this time, we need to check `connectionStrings` in ʻApp.config`.

In order to help more forum users, it is recommended that everyone can refer to the following tutorial.

[Entity Framework Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/create-entity-data-model.aspx)