# Connection String for EntityFramework Core in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-sql-database

I'm having an issue with an Azure SQL DB (SQL PaaS) connection string in my Azure Web App. It is defined in the "Connection Strings" settings of the Application Config. I see the Conn String value (format below) in https://myAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml#connectionStrings. My defined Conn String name is "MyApp" and Azure is prefixing it with "SQLAZURECONNSTR_" as you'd expect.

```
SQLAZURECONNSTR_MyApp = Server=tcp:mysvr.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyApp;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user@mysvr;Password=passWord;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

In Startup.cs, I have this though I'm not certain it is necessary.

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
[...]
            services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyApp")));
```

And in my database context class, I have the following:

```cs
    public partial class MyAppContext : DbContext
    {
[...]
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .Build();
                var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyApp");
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }
        }
    }
```

When accessing the web app executing a method that connects to the database, I'm receiving a null reference to the conn string.

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(string value, string parameterName)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, string connectionString, Action<SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder> sqlServerOptionsAction)
myapp.Models.MyAppContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in MyAppContext.cs
```

No conn strings are defined in the local .json file, though I'll want to add that back for development purposes at some point.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

**NEWEST**

**Code First.**

[Database Initialization in Entity Framework 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx)

connectionStr should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolDBConnectionString" connectionString="tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db; Persist Security Info=False; User ID=user;Password=mypassword; MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**PRIVIOUS**

DB First.

Your project use `ef core`, so the `connectionstrings` should be like below.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SchoolDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SchoolDB.csdl|res://*/SchoolDB.ssdl|res://*/SchoolDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=SchoolDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**For more details, you can refer my answer in the post.**

[Timeout period elasped prior to obtaining a connection from the pool - Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062815/timeout-period-elasped-prior-to-obtaining-a-connection-from-the-pool-entity-fr/63069572#63069572)

**You can also refer to this tutorial, which will help you.**

[Entity Framework Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/create-entity-data-model.aspx)

Comment: That conn string is only valid for DB first models. I'm using code first. The conn string as-is in my post works given I'm running it on my local dev machine provided it is in appsettings.json.